# Edit ViewModel Error with the Edit action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm

I am trying to get an edit viewmodel to work. On [httpget], it works no problem, but on the [httppost], it won't save/update to the database right. It sends me to my http  Error 404.0 - Not found.

Here is my code:

Edit Action in my Festival Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit2(int? id)
    {
        //Festival fest = db.Festivals.Include("County").Include("FestivalType").Include("Towns").Where(x => x.FestivalId == id).Single();
        Festival fest = db.Festivals.Where(x => x.FestivalId == id).FirstOrDefault();

        FestivalVM festival = new FestivalVM { SelectedCounty = fest.FestivalCounty.ID, endDate = fest.EndDate, FestivalName = fest.FestivalName, SelectedFestivalType = fest.FType.ID, startDate = fest.StartDate, SelectedTown = fest.FestivalTown.ID };
        if (fest != null)
        {

            festival.County = db.Counties.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.Name);
            festival.FestivalType = db.FestivalTypes.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.FType);
            festival.FestivalType.Add(-1, "----- Add New Festival Type -----");
            festival.Towns = db.Towns.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.Name);

            festival.startDate = (from f in db.Festivals where fest.FestivalId == id select f.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();  

            festival.endDate = (from f in db.Festivals where fest.FestivalId == id select f.EndDate).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(festival);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit2(FestivalVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid != true)
        {
            if (model.SelectedFestivalType != -1)
            {
                Festival f = new Festival();
                //db.save stuff from create.
                f.EndDate = model.endDate.Date;
                f.FestivalCounty = db.Counties.Where(p => p.ID == model.SelectedCounty).Single();
                f.FestivalName = model.FestivalName;
                f.FType = db.FestivalTypes.Where(p => p.ID == model.SelectedFestivalType).Single();
                f.StartDate = model.startDate.Date;

                f.FestivalTown = db.Towns.Where(p => p.ID == model.SelectedTown).Single();
                f.UserID = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;


                //db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Festival", new { id = f.FestivalId });
                //String test = "test3";
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "No Festival Type Picked");
        }
        model.County = db.Counties.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.Name);
        model.FestivalType = db.FestivalTypes.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.FType);
        model.FestivalType.Add(-1, "----- Add New -----");
        model.Towns = db.Towns.ToDictionary(p => p.ID, q => q.Name);
        model.startDate = DateTime.Now;
        model.endDate = DateTime.Now;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Edit View

```
@model MyFestival.Models.FestivalVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Your Festival";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Festival.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit Your Festival</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FestivalName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FestivalName, new{@class = "form-control", @style="width:250px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FestivalName, null, new {@style="color:red;"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.startDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startDate, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:250px" })
            <input class="form-control datepicker" style="width:250px" name="startDate" placeholder="Please pick date..."/>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startDate, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.endDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.endDate, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:250px" })
            <!--<input class="form-control datepicker" style="width:250px" name="endDate" placeholder="Please pick date..."/>-->
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.endDate, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Towns, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(p=> p.SelectedTown ,Model.Towns.Select(p=> new SelectListItem(){Text=p.Value.ToString(), Value=p.Key.ToString(),Selected=false}), new{@class = "form-control", @style="width:250px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Towns, null, new {@style="color:red;"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.County, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(p=> p.SelectedCounty, Model.County.Select(p=> new SelectListItem(){Text=p.Value.ToString(),Value=p.Key.ToString(), Selected=false}), new{@class = "form-control", @style="width:250px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.County, null, new {@style="color:red;"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FestivalType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(p=> p.SelectedFestivalType, Model.FestivalType.Select(p=> new SelectListItem(){Text=p.Value.ToString(),Value=p.Key.ToString(), Selected=false}),  new{@class = "form-control", @style="width:250px"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FestivalType, null, new {@style="color:red;"})
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />

            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
}

@Html.Partial("CreateFestivalType", new MyFestival.Models.FestivalTypeVM())

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { // will trigger when the document is ready
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                currentText: 'Now'
            }); //Initialise any date pickers
        });
</script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#SelectedFestivalType').change(function () {
                if ($(this).find(":selected").val() == -1) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    $('.focus :input:first').focus();
                }
            });
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxResponse(data) {
        alert("This Worked and the Data ID is: " + data.FestivalTypeID);
        var newOption = "<option value='" + data.FestivalTypeID + "'>" + data.Name + "</option>";
        $('#SelectedFestivalType').append(newOption);
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');

        $("#SelectedFestivalType option[value='" + data.FestivalTypeID + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
    };
</script>
}
```

Comment: @TMcKeown its just been added

Comment: Controller/View models don't match, check my answer.

Comment: Sorry @TMcKeown the proper edit view is there now

Comment: have you tried specifying the controller method in the Html.BeginForm() method?  Indicate that it is a post also.

Comment: The page returns to the index page, but it wont save the changes.

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit2", "Festival", FormMethod.Post))`

Comment: see my NEW answer... please upvote/check it... need them points.

Comment: wondering why DB is not created in the method?  Are you creating a global or instance DB???  wondering how you are managing that..

Answer (score 0):

To save your changes add this line before calling db.SaveChanges():

```
db.Festival.Add( f );
```

You are not adding to the context.

Comment: But why `db.Festival.Add(f);` ?? that creates a festival. Should it not be `db.Entry(f).State = EntityState.Modified;`?

Even thought I did try it using the EntityState.Modified but I get this error : **Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.**

I will..

Comment: my point was your Festival object was not "attached" to the dbContext.